# Attach Debugger tool missing in Office Word 2021

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I am using Office Word 2021 and building an add-in. But I cannot find the Attach Debugger tool in the Personality menu?

Comment: Do you mean one-time purchase (not subscription) Word 2021?

Comment: yes the one time purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it seems like only one-time purchase does not have such functionality

> In Office 2016 on Windows, Build 77xx.xxxx or later, you can attach the debugger from the task pane.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).